# How to generate a matrix with consecutive/continues integers like [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]... ]?

Tags: python, matrix, logic

```
I have n rows and m columns I need a matrix which consists of consecutive m numbers like 1,2,3,4 this in each of the n rows that needs to be in ever increasing order.      
example: 3 X 4 matrix\
**[\
[1, 2, 3, 4], \
[5, 6, 7, 8],\
[9, 10, 11, 12]\
]**
```

The intuition is very simple. What we need is our **starting element in eaxh row should be the next element of the previous row's last element**. That is the only tricky part in this problem.
For that we start our next row generation with ***arr[i-1][-1]* to the *arr[i-1][-1] + m***. But for the **first row generation** we **start from 1** since the matrix is empty.

**Code**

```
mat = []

n,m = map(int,input().split())
for row in range(n):

    # if the row is starting row we start it with 1
    # Else we assign k to the prev rows 
    if row == 0:
        k = 1
    else:
        k = mat[row-1][-1] + 1   

    x = []

    #the new row starts from previous rows last elemnt + 1
    for j in range(k,k+m):
        x.append(j)
    mat.append(x)    
print(mat)
```

Comment: How is this related to digital signature algorithm (DSA)?

Answer (score 0):

First generate a continuous sequence of numbers and then adjust the format, with reference to either:(n and m represent the number of rows and columns respectively)

1. use the built-in functions, array to generate sequences, reshape to adjust the layout

```
import numpy as np
n, m = map(int, input().split())
res = np.arange(1, n*m+1).reshape(n, m)
print(res)
```

2. using list generative

```
items = list(range(1, m*n+1))
res = [items[i:i+m] for i in range(0, len(items), m)]
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a one liner to achieve that -

```
row, col = 3, 4

mat = [[col*i + j for j in range(1, col+1)] for i in range(row)]

print(mat)
```